# Relationship betweeen commutativity of linear maps and their matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have an inner product space $V$ and two linear maps $S,T\in \mathcal L(V)$. $S,T$ have matrices $M(S),M(T)$ w.r.t. some basis of $V$. 
Assume that $M(S), M(T)$ commute, i.e.
$$
M(S)M(T)=M(T)M(S).
$$
Can we draw the conclusion that $S$ and $T$ commute, and how to prove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can. Use the fact that there exists an isomorphism of *algebras*

$$L(V)\cong M_n(V)\;,\;\;T\mapsto M(T)$$

using your notation. BTW, it doesn't matter whether the matrix representation is wrt an orthonormal or whatever basis.

Comment: So I guess the proof goes as $M(ST)=M(S)M(T)=M(T)M(S)=M(TS)$ and then $ST=TS$ because isomorphism is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is defined such that it corresponds to composition of linear maps. Hence the claim is true.